# FormView insert, edit, update without datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to have gridviews or formviews to do the edit/insert/delete functionality but without the use of Sqldatasource in the aspx file.

I have the datasource wired up but the edit mode does not fire. I've tried with an external linkbutton to raise the mode change, as well as with the link button inside the ItemTemaplate but non of them worked (unless I added a SqlDataSource.

I understand that I have to code the BLLs and DALs, which I already have but I'm having difficulties with the CommandName objects. How do I capture this event?

I certain this has been addressed before but most of my searches only revealed ways using SqlDatasource or objectDataSource.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very good examples on Code Project one of them are

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667599/Add-Edit-update-Delete-gridview
2. http://weblogs.asp.net/manojkdotnet/archive/2009/10/11/insert-update-and-delete-using-grid-view-and-objectdatasource.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking for a solution for a formview.

Comment: @Risho in your question you have mentioned **gridview or formview** ?

Comment: I guess I didn't word it adequately. I do need solution for both.